# Camera2 API Stop Preview from Rotating

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm following [Camera2 Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and I'm trying to stop the preview from rotating when the phone's orientation changes. If you open the stock camera app in Android, the camera preview doesn't rotate when you rotate your phone but rather the interface around it. This is the effect I want to achieve.

Comment: I think that that is simply a locked orientation and then the icons for the various controls are rotated individually when there is an orientation change detected.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I guess a locked orientation doesn't mean orientation change can't be detected at all